# How do I create N VMs with M disks created and attached per VM?

Tags: azure, count, terraform

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine" { 
    count = var.vm_count 
    name  = "${local.vm_name}${count.index +1}"

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "datadisk01" {
    count              = var.disk_count  
    **virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine[count.index].id
    managed_disk_id    = element("${module.DISK.datadisk_id}","${count.index}")

}
```

Issue - I have 2 diffenent count varaibles vm_count and disk_count.
I want a generic solution, Ex. If vm count is 2 and each VM should have 3 datadisk i.e. disk_count is 3.

I am able to create multiple VMs and Disks as per the count. But facing issue while vm and disk attachment, as i am not able to use 2 counts in same resource.
How to handle this situation?

facing issue on the line maked as**

In summary, I want to create vm_count (N) VMs, with disk_count (M) disks created and attached to *each* VM.

How do I create N VMs with M disks created and attached per VM?

Comment: You wish something along the lines of double `for-loop`? First loop over `vm_count`, then `disk_count` and create 6 `azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment`?

Comment: yes, i am looking for similar solution. But, here the issue is i have used count in VM resource and disk resource, if i used for loop then how to fetch the virtual_machine_id ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like this using a set of indexes:

```
locals {

  indexes = {
    for vmi in range(var.vm_count): vmi => [
      for ddi in range(var.disk_count):
        ddi
    ]
  }

}
```

Which will create a map like this:

```
{
  "0" = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
  ]
  "1" = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
  ]
}
```

For later usage in this way:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "datadisk01" {
    for_each = local.indexes

    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine[tonumber(each.key)].id
    managed_disk_id    = element("${module.DISK.datadisk_id}","${each.value[0]}")
}
```

I haven't fully tested the output as the VM needs more configuration. However as I can see you are using `locals` for `vm_name` I would create a map/object with VM names containing the index, the values and the desired disks.

I hope this help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i've been able to have 2 loops in a resource is using a dynamic block.

Something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine" { 
    count = var.vm_count 
    name  = "${local.vm_name}${count.index +1}"

    dynamic "setting" {
     for_each = var.disk_count
     content {
        ##Storage_disk block
     }
   }
```

You can then access the index with each.value if required.